# i added background-image on my cite but it doesn't work

Tags: css, sass, background-image

I absolutely sure that i pointed correct way to file. And i have no idea why it doesn't work. Probably somebody already met this problem.

css file:
[image: css file]

how it looks in cite:
[image: how it looks in cite]

Mistake in DEV tools:
[image: Mistake in DEV tools]

Any support appreciated

I tried to point different way to image and make background color white but it doesn't work

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about not posting pictures of text (including code and error messages).

Answer (score 0):

The error says the file can not be found. The file path is incorrect. File paths are hard to figure out, so you can copy the path with VS code. Just check file paths and everything will work. In the future, "try uploading text code instead of an image of the code". (Stack Overflow Guidelines) Also, this may work in production, it might be because its on a local host not a web server.